# Excel code to create multiple copies of a sheet, copies named based on list in other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm a relatively basic Excel user and need help with something that I know is possible but is too complex for me to figure out.

Basically, I have a list in a sheet on Excel (called 'List'), and each entry on the list will require a sheet of its own, copied from an original that has already been set up (called 'RJF'). The list begins on row 6.

Column A in the 'List' sheet has a code for each list item. Column B has the name of each list item.

For each item in 'List' the value in Column A needs to be used to name the copied sheet, and also pull through to Cell A1 of the copy. The entry in Column B needs to pull through to Cell B1 of the copy.

Please can someone help me with this? I've found similar queries with answers but always with additional requirements which I don't know how to remove without affecting the aspects I do want.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide a mockup or screenshots so people can understand the nature and structure of the data.  Your description is too ambiguous.  You can use a comment to include the link to screenshots at a sharing service like imgur.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original poster. Apologies for not posting in line with normal practice. I found some code similar to what I needed in an answer to a reasonably similar query. I adapted it to what I needed:

```
Sub MoreAndMoreSheets()

Dim ListSh As Worksheet, BaseSh As Worksheet
Dim NewSh As Worksheet
Dim ListOfNames As Range, LRow As Long, cell As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Set ListSh = .Sheets("List")
    Set BaseSh = .Sheets("Base")
End With

LRow = ListSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '--Get last row of list.
Set ListOfNames = ListSh.Range("A6:A" & LRow) '--Qualify our list.

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False '--Turn off flicker.
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual '--Turn off calculations.
End With

For Each cell In ListOfNames '--For every name in list...
    BaseSh.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) '--Copy Base sheet.
    Set NewSh = ActiveSheet '--Let's name it NewSh.
    With NewSh
        On Error GoTo Boom '--In case of errors.
        .Name = cell.Value '--Set the sheet's name to that of our current name in list.
        GoTo LetUsContinue '--Skip to the LetUsContinue block.
Boom: '--In case of duplicate names...
        .Name = "Dup" & cell.Value '--Add "Dup" to beginning.
        .Tab.ColorIndex = 53 '--Change the tab color of the duplicate tab to orange for easy ID.
LetUsContinue:
        On Error GoTo 0 '--Turn off error handling.
        .Range("A1") = cell.Value
        .Calculate '--Calculate page.

    End With
Next cell

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True '--Return to proper state.
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic '--Return to automatic calculation.
End With

BaseSh.Activate '--Select Base.
MsgBox "Done!" '--Done!

End Sub
```

I used a vlookup referring to the list sheet in cell B1 of the Base sheet which accomplished what I wanted in regards to the second column pulling through:

=VLOOKUP(A1,'List'!A6:B500,2,FALSE)

Thanks to TheLaughingMan, should he ever read this, as his was the code that I adapted.

Comment: You have accidentally created two accounts, probably by creating unregistered accounts across multiple devices. You should first [register an account](https://superuser.com/users/signup) and then use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" to have your accounts merged. In order to merge them you will need to provide links to the two accounts, for your information these are http://superuser.com/users/517729/user517729 and http://superuser.com/users/517806/user517729. You'll then be able to edit, comment on and accept answers to this question.